# Google Rejected App due to "Privacy policy link invalid or missing"

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, google-apps, android-app-bundle

Google rejected Android App due to "Privacy policy link invalid or missing"
We have already updated the privacy policy in app as well on web.

[Rejection Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oirda.png)

Anyone has any idea why google is rejecting this?
I have seen other apps with similar functionality with different wording on their privacy policy and they are available on google store.

Comment: Just add a Privacy Policy page on your website or somewhere else publicly accessible & add that link to the App's info. You can easily generate one online with: https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: we have already added the privacy policy page on our web as well inside the the app as well a prominent disclosure popup before using location services.

Comment: Have you added that policy link in Google Play Developer Console?

Comment: yes we have added that in Google Play Developer console.

Comment: do you have any idea if they are looking for any specific format?

Answer (score 13):

For anyone having this issue.

I had this issue for months now..And I finally fixed it.

Conclusion:
Your Privacy Policy has to work WITHOUT Javascript.
Mine was part of a Vue.js app.

I switched it to a plain HTML Page and it got accepted.

Comment: what? but why? did they note that somewhere ?

Comment: Anyone know the requirements for this? our policy is on a vue site but the content is perfectly readable with JS off

Comment: No, I just used plain html file and it worked. You can look it up on GitHub: leonlatsch/homepage  Its also a vue app butz with the policy in the public directory

Comment: At the end this worked! Thank you man!

Answer (score 3):

On rejection email there was appeal link, clicked on that and explained the privacy policy.
As well asked them to tell us more if we are missing anything specific.
After appeal app was approved next day.

Comment: We are having a similar issue. any guidance on how your resoved with would be much appreciated. We also have out privacy policy online and in app. The app also displays a prominent two step disclosure when requesting location access.

Comment: Ok, so I tried accessing out policy page from a VPN from a different country. Our site was actually GEO locked. Check that the privacy policy is actually accessible to users accross the globe!

Comment: I've gone through two support reps and both weren't interested in realizing that our Privacy Policy was valid. I'm needing to stand up a different Privacy Policy that is not part of a JS client app to get around it, hopefully it works.